# make of base64 a downloadabe file?

Tags: php

I'm posting base64 encoded binary data to a php page which contains the following code :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["base64data"])) {
     $data = $_POST["base64data"];
     $decoded = base64_decode($data);
     $thetitle = "yourfile.out";

     header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$thetitle);
     header("Content-Length: ".strlen($decoded));
     header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
}
?>
```

This code correctly shows the Save As dialog on browser. However the downloaded file is 0 bytes ?

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You are just sending some headers, but after that you are not outputting _any_ data …?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually output `$decoded`.

Can we chalk this up as a good case of the Mondays? :D or perhaps .. *it can't be helped*.